# Sorting alpha-numeric data with jQuery DataTables in client side processing mode

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

So I have a table that have alpha-numeric values for example:

```
8980
1100
A1100
BA200
```

I want it to sort it in a numeric order fashion first and then in alpha-numeric fashion e.g.

```
1000 
8980
A1100
BA200
```

Found some help here but not exactly the thing I am looking for: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/367/bug-sort-number-column-and-stype

Is there a way to achieve this using any API?

Comment: What order do you want `A25` and `A200` to be sorted? All your examples would sort as you expect with a naïve string sort.

Comment: Phylogenesis, the one having an alphabet should be sorted as a string and the one`s without it should be sorted as numerical values.

Answer (score 7):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [Natural sorting](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural) plug-in to sort data with a mix of numbers and letters naturally.

For example, use the code below to sort first column (`targets: 0`) using natural sorting plug-in.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [ { targets: 0, type: 'natural' } ]    
});
```

Don't forget to include plug-in [JavaScript file](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural#CDN).

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzh8pvch/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I am using npm package and i have datatable package installed. is there a different package for natural sorting?

Comment: @leedz, the plugin code is 60 lines or something like that.  Cant you just hold it static somewhere in your code?

Comment: I know it's pretty late in answering, but i stumbled upon this solution and thought would share --- {
                            'data': 'YourColumnHere',
                            'sType': 'num'
                }

Comment: The Natural Sorting solution worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: natural sorting is not working when you have a mixed of  lowercase and uppercase alphanumeric values, in the above jsfiddle I replace the first row value with "i3" and its not sorting 
https://jsfiddle.net/jeanpokou/nLwz9yma/1/